# How can I truncate serializer CharField value if it exceeds a certain length

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model field that I want to restrict to a certain length (`max_length=2000`). I however want the serializer to truncate any value that exceeds that length (`max_length=2000`) without failing the validation if a given string exceeds the limit. How can I achieve this

model field

```
description = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
```

serializer field

```
description = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=2000, required=False,
        allow_blank=True, default=""
    )
```

For example, if the serializer is called with a value of len= 2005, I want the validation to truncate the value to [:2000] and not raise an error.

Comment: can you explain what do you want to do when the length is greater than 2000 and when it's less than 2000?

Comment: @VishalSingh If a string is below 2000, the validation will pass as it always works, but if it is more than 2000, I want the validation to truncate the string to 2000 and not raise an error.

Comment: That answer truncates the string but still raises the 400 status code meaning the validation fails. @VishalSingh

Comment: did you try removing the `max_length= 2000` from the char field?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom field:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers


class TruncatedCharField(serializers.CharField):
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        if self.max_length and data and len(data) > self.max_length:
            return data[: self.max_length - 3] + "..."
        return data
```

And in your case:

```py
description = models.TruncatedCharField(max_length=2000)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [field-level validation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation) to restrict the length of the string and do any custom operation that you want.

```
def validate_description(self, value):
    return value[:2000]
```

Comment: This still fails the validation for a string bigger than 2000 characters or 200 in your example

Comment: @Anjayluh in your post it's 200 but in your code example, it's 2000. so what is it?

Comment: I've updated it to 2000.

Comment: @Anjayluh remove the `max_length` validator from the char field.